# What does the number before each keyword in a LDA topic mean?

Tags: gensim, lda

I have only one document and use LDA to find just one topic. Here is what I got:

```
[(0,
  '0.032*"women" + 0.032*"gender" + 0.032*"tech" + 0.032*"amazons" + 0.021*"peers" + 0.021*"positions" + 0.021*"policymakers" + 0.021*"practices" + 0.021*"markets" + 0.021*"number"')]
```

How should I understand the number before each keyword?

Comment: Your question looks like duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120031/in-lda-how-to-interpret-the-meaning-of-topics